# How to paginate data from remote db in Typo3?

Tags: pagination, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I wrote a website using TYPO3 7 CMS. Now I need to display database content in frontend(like on the picture). But I don't have any idea, how to do that. I've searched for a coresponding plugin in TYPO3 repository and found `cag_tables`. But it doesn't work cause it for version 6.0...

[image]

Comment: do you use fluid for template rendering ?

Comment: Yes. I wrote whole site as an extension with using of fluid and partials

Answer (score 1):

Use the `paginate` `widget` `viewhelper`:

```
<f:widget.paginate objects="{blogs}" as="paginatedBlogs" configuration="{itemsPerPage: 5, insertAbove: 1, insertBelow: 0, maximumNumberOfLinks: 10}">
use {paginatedBlogs} as you used {blogs} before, most certainly inside
a <f:for> loop.
</f:widget.paginate>
```

https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/Widget/PaginateViewHelper.html